# How to design a task scheduler in nodejs with rabbitmq that won't run the same task when spanning multiple process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm trying to implement RabbitMQ as a general task queue in an existing web app. But I also need to run a scheduled task to aggregate some user data at a set interval.

I know task scheduling isn't in the core design of rabbitMQ but it seems like it can be done with dead letter exchanges. But what I'm concern about is that when I have multiple instances of the web app running the task will get scheduled multiple times.

Is there a way I can structure this to avoid this problem? Perhaps limiting the amount of connection an exchange if that is possible?

Comment: are you using redis? Do you have to use RabbitMQ? Have a look at [node-resque](https://github.com/taskrabbit/node-resque) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you've said it's not in the core design of RabbitMQ.

You can take a look at RabbitMQ blog to figure out how they solving problems with semaphore queue. https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/02/19/distributed-semaphores-with-rabbitmq/

"when I have multiple instances of the web app running the task will get scheduled multiple times." 
This is true, but you can change your setup  a little bit. Ether introduce a "shared memory" (say db with primary key enforcement). And make sure you publish to rabbit only after your transaction suceeded. 
Or you can take a look  at sort of "round robin" exchange and leverage it entirely in RabbitMQ context (https://github.com/jbrisbin/random-exchange)